what type of polynomials are these? similar to laguerre polynomial generating function.
I'm studying polynomials generated as coefficients of this generating function:
$$ [x^n]f(x) = [x^n] \frac{\cos(t\frac{1-x}{1+x})}{(1-x^2)^{\frac{1}{4}}}$$
This is kind of similar to Laguerre polynomial generating function:
$$ \frac{e^{-\frac{xt}{1-x}}}{(1-x)^{a+1}} $$
Here are a few of the first:
$$[x^0]f(x) = \cos(t)$$
$$[x^1]f(x) = 2t\sin(t)$$
$$[x^2]f(x) = \left(\frac{1}{4} - 2t^2\right)\cos(t) -2t\sin(t)$$
$$[x^3]f(x) = 4t^2\cos(t) +\left(\frac{5}{2}t - \frac{4}{3}t^3\right) \sin(t)$$
$$[x^4]f(x) = \left(\frac{2}{3}t^4 - \frac{13}{2}t^2 + \frac{5}{32}\right)\cos(t) +\left(4 t^3 -\frac{5}{2} t\right) \sin(t)$$
What are the polynomials that are attached to the $\cos(t)$ and $\sin(t)$?

One cannot have an idea on such a short list. You know that to qualify as a "respectable family ", your polynomials should verify a second order differential equation, or a second order recurrence relation, or an orthogonality relationship wrt a certain weight function. Do you have a computer algebra tool giving you arbitrary long sequences of these polynomials, beginning in particular to understand the parity of these polynomials (it looks that we have sequences odd,odd,even,even, etc) ?

Interesting problem ! They are generated by two complicated recurrecne relations that I shall not type. If you hva Mathematica, I could show you.

@JeanMarie. Would you like to have more terms ? The reccurence relation is of   fifth order.

@Claude Leibovici Hi Claude ! I wasn't thinking that there exist higher order polynomial recurrences than degree 2... Honestly, I don't know if, having more terms, I would be able to deduce anything, in particular a possible orthogonality wrt a weight function which would be the Graal !
